# SYBASE :Join Two table where Value of one table column is column name of other table

Tags: sql, join, metadata, sybase

```
  Table1 

PRICE   ID_1    ID_2    ID_3
 500    1       2       3
 750    2       3       4  


Table2

ID  VALUE  
ID_1    1  
ID_2    2  
ID_3    3
```

I have two tables and want to join these tables like

```
Select * from table1 T1 Join Table2 T2 on
T1.(T2.ID) = T2.Value
```

In short I want to convert one table column value to other table column name at the time of joining.

**EDITED**
Result should be like this:

```
PRICE   ID_1    ID_2    ID_3  
 500    1       2       3
```

Comment: That is actually a really bad table design. Can you change it?

Comment: Nope. That is not my design. It is existing since ages.

Comment: When it is existing that long in your company then sure there are already solutions how to do this simple join.

Comment: thanks buddy for your time.

Comment: @gauravbharadwaj . . . Edit your question and show the results that you want.  It is unclear to me what the results should be.  What is being used for the `join`?  `t1.(t2.id)` doesn't make sense.

Comment: @GordonLinoff put the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method is:

```
Select *
from table1 T1 Join
     Table2 T2
     on t1.id_1 = T2.Value and t2.id = 'ID_1' or
        t1.id_2 = T2.Value and t2.id = 'ID_2' or
        t1.id_3 = T2.Value and t2.id = 'ID_3';
```

This is not efficient, but it should accomplish the logic you want.

EDIT:

Based on your edit, you appear to want:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where exists (select 1 from table2 where t2.value = t1.id_1 and t2.id = 'ID_1') and
      exists (select 1 from table2 where t2.value = t1.id_2 and t2.id = 'ID_2') and
      exists (select 1 from table2 where t2.value = t1.id_3 and t2.id = 'ID_3') ;
```

Comment: That is good but my problem is that IDs  may be multiple. Like i mentioned in one of my comment ..
ID_1, ID_2, ID_3,...ID_1000 and it is not necessary that Table2 will have all IDs

Comment: @gauravbharadwaj . . . Then you need 1000 conditions.  Simple enough.  Or fix the data structure.  This answers the question that you actually asked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the rows into columns from the second table first, then join the two tables:

```
Select * 
from table1 T1 
join
(

    SELECT
      MAX(case when id = 'ID_1' THEN Value ELSE 0 END) AS ID_1,
      MAX(case when id = 'ID_1' THEN Value ELSE 0 END) AS ID_2,
      MAX(case when id = 'ID_1' THEN Value ELSE 0 END) AS ID_3
    from table

) as T2  on T1.ID_1 = T2.ID_1
        and T1.ID_2 = T2.ID_2
        and T1.ID_3 = T2.ID_3
```

Or do it the other way, convert table a columns into rows:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT 'ID_1' AS ID, ID_1 AS Value from table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'ID_2' AS ID, ID_2 AS Value from table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'ID_3' AS ID, ID_3 AS Value from table1
) AS t1
INNER JOIN Table2 as T2  on T1.ID_1 = T2.ID_1
                        and T1.ID_2 = T2.ID_2
                        and T1.ID_3 = T2.ID_3;
```

Comment: What if there are number of IDs possible. I mean ID_1, ID_2, ID_3 ...... ID_1000.

Comment: @gauravbharadwaj In this case you have to do it dynamically using dynamic sql.

Comment: Can you explain how?

Comment: @gauravbharadwaj Unfortunately I am not familiar with sybase but I can show you how to do it in mysql. But it is not hard, you just need to repeat the same case expression or union for all the values using the dynamic sql.